# Click Event Times Out with Selenium in C# with Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have searched all over and can't find an answer to this issue.

I am trying to have my code click a button. That specific button frequently takes more than 60 seconds (1:27 to be exact) to finish loading the next item.

So I have tried `implicitwait` and `scripttimeout` but they don't work because "I may be missing a using or reference assembly" but I have looked for that and it seems I have everything I need so I think it may not be used anymore.

So it looks like this :

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"consolidateAll\"]").Click();
```

I don't know if I could add a wait time of some sort in that click event to let it wait a certain amount of time or what, but I would love some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: The driver waits for the page to be "complete" to return. The page is most likely failing to load a resource (image, script, analytic...). Check the console to see if it's the case.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials along with the error stack trace (if any)

Comment: Please update the question with the exact error message and stack-trace. BTW, "I may be missing a using or reference assembly" is a compilation error, which probably indicates a typing error, though at least `ImplicitWait` wouldn't probably help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
// wait for an element to be clickable
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"consolidateAll\"]")));
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"consolidateAll\"]").Click();
```

Made a function for you :

```
/**
 * Wait for an element to be clickable in the dom, then click it.
 */
public void ClickElementSafe(this WebElement element, WebDriver driver, int timeout)
{
    // wait for it to be clickable
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));

    // click it
    element.Click();
}
```